# Use array in multi dimensional array Vue

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a computed property that gets a currency array from an API

I then want to check if the currency array exists and return it

```
currencies() {
        let currency =  this.$store.getters.getCurrencies;
        return this.currency.includes(this.quoteCurrency)
    },
```

My array looks like so:

```
data: 
{
    "data": [
        {
            "code": "AUD",
            "name": "Australian Dollar",
            "symbol": "$"
        },
        {
            "code": "CAD",
            "name": "Canadian Dollar",
            "symbol": "$"
        },
        {
            "code": "EUR",
            "name": "Euro",
            "symbol": "€"
        },
        {
            "code": "MXN",
            "name": "Mexican Peso",
            "symbol": "$"
        },
        {
            "code": "MAD",
            "name": "Moroccan Dirham",
            "symbol": "د.م.‏"
        },
        {
            "code": "USD",
            "name": "US Dollar",
            "symbol": "$"
        },
        {
            "code": "GBP",
            "name": "Pound Sterling",
            "symbol": "£"
        }
    ]
}
```

and I have a data point

```
quoteCurrency: "GBP"
```

I get 'Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined"'

Answer (score 0):

you are using `this.currency` for a local variable. Use

```
currency.includes( // do the stuff )
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined a local variable with `let` so you probably want to write this instead:

```
return currency.includes(this.quoteCurrency)
```

If you need to use `this` then first declare `currency` in your `data` section and assign the value to `this.currency` instead of defining a new variable.